# "LANG: Undefined variable" when running a ssh command

Tags: linux, fedora

I have found a problem in our FC8 linux machines with the LANG variable when running a command through ssh.

When in a terminal, I can see that my LANG variable is "es_ES"

```
[angelv@italia ~]$ echo $LANG
es_ES
```

If I connect back to my machine through ssh, there are no problems and $LANG is still "es_ES"

```
[angelv@italia ~]$ ssh italia
Last login: Mon Jul 26 12:51:12 2010 from XXXXXXXXXXXX
[angelv@italia ~]$ echo $LANG
es_ES
[angelv@italia ~]$
```

But if I try to run a command with ssh, then that variable is undefined...

```
[angelv@italia ~]$ ssh italia 'echo $LANG'
LANG: Undefined variable.
[angelv@italia ~]$
```

Does anybody know where I should look to find the culprit?

Comment: My shell is tcsh, so the file that is not loaded in a non-login shell is ~/.login 

Following that file solved the issue.

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 3):

Quoth the SSH manual:

> If command is specified, it is
>   executed on the remote host instead of
>   a login shell.

Login shells behave quite differently than non-login shells, most notably here in that they don't usually source the the login `.profile` files. See your shell documentation for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, your locale variable is generally listed in `/usr/share/locale`. You should check on the server machin what local they use. It may differ from your machine.

EDIT: sorry I mistake the question.

in bash you should do

```
export LANG="es_ES"
```

in other shell you may have to use `setenv` instead of `export`

Comment: note that LANG is set properly when an interactive shell was started but not with direct command execution; that was the clue that it wasn't a missing `export` as I too thought on first look.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to work around this feature of ssh by invoking your shell and asking it to act like a login shell:

```
ssh italia "sh -l -c 'echo $LANG'"
```

Depending on the actual shell you're using, the required option might be `-l` or something else.